# jQuery auto play script of pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My Script :**

```
function pagination(id)
    {

    $("#article_load_destacados").load("indexer_destacados_news.php?pg_d="+id);


    if (id+1>2)
    {        
       pagination(0);

       setInterval(function() 
       {
          pagination(0);
        }, 4000);        
    }
    else
    {        
       setInterval(function() 
       {
         pagination(id+1);
       }, 4000);        
    }
    }

    </script>

    <div id="article_load_destacados"></div>

    <script>
    pagination(0);
    </script>
```

Create this script for show pagination, the script call PHP file and load this with pagination, for this send different ids and when load PHP file load the same time different elements of pagination. With this script I want run all pagination based on id. If I have for example 5 pages, the script run from 0 to 5, I use for `setInterval` for it with jQuery.

I want get the script paginate and send different id each 4 seconds.
The problem when run the script the navigator doesn't work, and generates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out you want setTimeout not setInterval, you can also simplify your code http://jsfiddle.net/rayBt/

```
var imax = 3;
var time = 500;
function pagination(id){
  $("#article_load_destacados").load("indexer_destacados_news.php?pg_d="+id);
  id = (id + 1) % imax;
  setTimeout(function () {
      pagination(id);
      }, time);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) is used to have a function repeat at a given interval. Because you're calling `setIntveral` recursively, your script will be executing `pagination` with many different values once pagination starts.

You should use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead. `setTimeout` starts a function after a given period of time, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I try with this you comment but no show one to one the pages each 4 seconds , the script show very quick pagination and i think somethings bad in script , in one moment go from page 0 or go to the page 3 , and block my navigator also , i don´t understand why , thank´s regards

Comment: Ah you should probably remove `pagination(0)` after `if (id+1>2)`